# Removing/Hiding scrollbar from <af:inlineFrame> in ADF

Tags: oracle-adf

I'm using  to display servlet output, but i'm getting scrollbar at on right side. How to get rid of this scrollbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the height to the height of the content in your iframe